# Dutch Passport South African citizen

Tags: netherlands, citizenship, south-african-citizens

My parents were both Dutch citizens and relocated to South Africa in 1949.  They are both deceased.  My daughter wants to apply for a Dutch passport.  Her father and myself are South African citizens.  Where do I start with the process and would she qualify?

Answer (score 5):

She would qualify only if:

1. Your parents were still Dutch citizens when you were born (making you a Dutch citizen at birth), and
2. You did not lose your Dutch nationality before your daughter was born, and
3. Your daughter acquired Dutch nationality at birth, and
4. Your daughter has not lost her Dutch nationality.

The rules governing these things have changed over the years, so it depends a bit on when you were born and when she was born.  Other factors to consider:

1. If your parents were naturalized in South Africa before you were born, they probably lost their Dutch nationality, so you were never Dutch.
2. If your parents were naturalized after your birth, but before you reached the age of majority under Dutch law, you may have lost your nationality at that point.  (If you were naturalized in South Africa, independently from your parents, but you were at the time a minor under Dutch law, then you *retained* Dutch nationality; if you had both South African and Dutch nationality from birth, then their being naturalized would have no effect on you, if I recall correctly.)
3. If you were 28 or older when your daughter was born, you need to consider whether you lost your Dutch nationality under the rule about living outside the Netherlands for more than 10 years.  That rule has changed a couple of times over the years, so specific dates are important.
4. If you were married to your daughter's father when she was born, you may not have passed Dutch nationality to her, depending on when she was born.
5. If your daughter is over 28 years old, she has probably lost any Dutch nationality she may have had because of the rule about living outside the Netherlands for more than 10 years.

> Where do I start with the process?

At whichever Dutch consulate has jurisdiction over your place of residence.